# Copy the cell format from .xlsx file using Spreadsheett::ParseXLSX to write another cell using EXCEL:WRITER::XLSX?

Tags: python, excel, perl, projects-and-solutions

Please check the code below. if I remove the $format from the last line to $sheet_write->write($row, $col,$cell -> value) then it works fine.

I am declaring to add the format in excel_2 spreadsheet which would be written by "Excel::Writer::XLSX;"  package. And I am coping the cell format($format= $cell->get_format();) from another reader parser "**use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX**". Any help would be appreciated. I am expecting there is some mismatch between these 2 different methods.

```
#!/home/utils/perl-5.24/5.24.2-058/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;


use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;


my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('abc.xlsx');
my $excel_2 = Excel::Writer::XLSX -> new ('abc_copied.xlsx');

my $format = $excel_2->add_format();

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}


for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {

    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();
    printf("Sheet: %s\n", $worksheet->{Name});

    my $sheet_write = $excel_2->add_worksheet($worksheet->{Name});

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
    for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            next unless $cell;

            print "Row, Col    = ($row, $col)\n";
            #print "Value       = ", $cell->value(),       "\n";
            #print "Unformatted = ", $cell->unformatted(), "\n";
            #print "\n";
            $format= $cell->get_format();
            $sheet_write->write($row, $col,$cell -> value,$format);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX's cell->get_format yields a different object than what Excel::Writer::XLSX is expecting as the format object in its `write` method.  Even though they both deal with spreadsheets, they are different modules and will very unlikely share a class in this manner.

The properties of Excel::Writer::XLSX's format object are well documented:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#CELL-FORMATTING

I see there is a clone format module:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::CloneXLSX::Format

No personal experience with it, but it looks promising...  Otherwise you will probably have to dump the contents of the Parse module, figure out what's most important to you, and then do the translations yourself.  But seriously, try the module.

Alternatively, if this is on a Windows machine, Win32::OLE may be better to handle this type of task for you if you are tethered to Perl (which needless to say would not be my first choice if your sole focus is Excel spreadsheet operations).

Comment: This is the third package I am using now for copying the just format. And its still not copying the conditional formatting and other functions like merging-columns etc. from one .XLSX sheet to another. The output looks very ugly. Is there any just one package to do all? I am open yo other scripting languages as well. I am doing some operation on cell values so i also need to copy cell by cell.

Comment: I also have added a new code here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60662789/how-to-copy-conditional-formatting-and-other-functions-like-merging-columns-etc?noredirect=1#comment107327066_60662789  Now I am open to any kind of solution who lets me do operation per cell. I would be okay to start with python, excel vb or perl package.

Comment: The question was closed, so I can't respond...  I would strongly recommend using VBA for this.  It's a miserable language that can't figure out if it wants to be OOP or not, but hand's-down the best one for doing anything related to MS Office, and it handles it all as bread-and-butter.  The best part is, you don't need to do any heavy lifting...  you can record your actions and let it do most of the work for you.

Comment: Opened it back. Let me check if I can apply the same rules to 1000 of excel sheets using some other script.

Comment: Question still appears closed...  Maybe re-post it as a VBA question?